# How to fix Hydration with supabase auth

Tags: reactjs, next.js, supabase

I started to work with NextJS, and I have this hydration error :
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

The Component :

```
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { supabase } from "@/lib/supabaseClient";
import { Auth } from "@supabase/auth-ui-react";
import { ThemeSupa } from "@supabase/auth-ui-shared";
import { Session } from "@supabase/supabase-js";

export default function Login() {
  const [session, setSession] = useState<Session | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    supabase.auth.getSession().then(({ data: { session } }) => {
      setSession(session);
    });

    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      const {
        data: { subscription },
      } = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((_event, session) => {
        setSession(session);
      });

      return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }, []);

  if (!session) {
    return (
      <div className="min-h-screen flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
        <div className="w-full max-w-md">
          <Auth
            supabaseClient={supabase}
            appearance={{
              theme: ThemeSupa,
            }}
            providers={[]}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for your helping ! :)

I want to understand why is hydration and how fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might probable have to wait until the component mounts. This simple old trick could fix it.

```
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { supabase } from "@/lib/supabaseClient";
import { Auth } from "@supabase/auth-ui-react";
import { ThemeSupa } from "@supabase/auth-ui-shared";
import { Session } from "@supabase/supabase-js";

export default function Login() {
  const [session, setSession] = useState<Session | null>(null);
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsMounted(true);

    supabase.auth.getSession().then(({ data: { session } }) => {
      setSession(session);
    });

    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      const {
        data: { subscription },
      } = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((_event, session) => {
        setSession(session);
      });

      return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }, []);

  if (!isMounted) {
    return null;
  }

  if (!session) {
    return (
      <div className="min-h-screen flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
        <div className="w-full max-w-md">
          <Auth
            supabaseClient={supabase}
            appearance={{
              theme: ThemeSupa,
            }}
            providers={[]}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```